# Vertically align content to the middle of a div?

Tags: css, sass

I have a div containing some content. It has a height of 31px and inside it, the button has smaller height.

```
<div class="headerAndButton">
    <h3 class="h3">
        Click the button to the right
        <button>click me</button>
    </h3>
</div>
```

I have another header that does not have a button in it.

```
<div class="headerAndButton">
    <h3 class="h3">No button here, I only want to have this header have the same vertical alignment, height and margin as the other header</h3>
</div>
```

I want to vertically align the `<h3>` text within each div. I have tried to solve the problem with the following SCSS:

```
.headerAndButton {
  margin-bottom: $space-300;

  h3 {
    min-height: 31px;
    vertical-align: bottom;

    button {
      margin-left: $space
    }
  }
}
```

The `vertical-align` property has no visible effect. The text in the  without the botton is top aligned. The text in the other  is a bit lower. It also becomes top aligned if I remove the button.

How can I make this headers have the same vertical alignment? I am not good at CSS, so maybe there are completely different better ways to solve this.

Comment: do you want to just vertical align the elements or should the header tags be on the same height, while one has a button below and the other does not?

Comment: The button is to the right of the header. I want the header texts to have the same vertical alignment inside of their divs so that it is easy for me that have equal space between the divs containing the headers and the body texts following them

Comment: Do you have the possibility to work with fixed font size for the header? Or do you have to create a dynamic solution?

Answer (score 16):

You could use several methods to vertical align an element. For example you could use new `display: flex` methods:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
flex-direction: column;
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/ndd0h97y/2/)

If its no problem to `position: absolute` your element you could use

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

There is a quite good tutorial from CSS-Tricks, named [**Centering in CSS: A Complete Guide**](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/).

Answer (score 3):

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

just apply this CSS code on headerAndButton

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:table-cell` then `vertical-align:middle` to do that.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/obaxmnbz/)

( I add a border so you can see the h3 is aligned )